# Laravel 5.2 rollback database with foreign key

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-5, database-migration

I'm trying to rollback my database, but have this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table `tb_levels`)
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

this is my migration code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

    Schema::create('tb_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id_user');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->integer('id_level')->unsigned();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->boolean('activated')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('id_level')->references('id_level')->on('tb_levels');
    });

    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::table('tb_users', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropForeign('tb_users_id_level_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('id_level');
    });
    Schema::drop('tb_users');
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

I've tried several ways that I found in this forum, but still got that error, any help please?

Answer (score 2):

First Disable Foreign Key using this:

> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
>
> SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

And then migrate your database.

Again Apply Foreign key constrain:

> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
>
> SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: um... is that for migrate database or rolling back database?

Comment: it will disable foreign key constraint and after that you can either migrate or rollback

Comment: where should I put that code? on mysql or on my code? I've try put it on my code but still show me that error.

Comment: First put code in MySQL and make operation whatever you want to apply

Comment: This may not be the best answer, but it solved the problem while I'm under the gun.  Thanks @SachinAghera

Answer (score 2):

Well, finally I found a way to solve that error,

First of all you need to make a migration to drop the foreign key and column, this is the code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

    Schema::table('tb_users', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropForeign('tb_users_id_level_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('id_level');
    });

    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

Then migrate it, after that It will drop the column and foreign key.

After that delete **Schema::table** code, save it, and run command:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

Well, It works but it's really an impractical way,

Hope that out there had more easy way rather than this.